# Unable to Savechanges in Entity Framework when Object return from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was developing simple MVC application that update record from the database. I've used BAL and Controller to get record and update like below

**Student.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.DAL
{
    public class Student
    {
        DemoDatabaseEntities db = new DemoDatabaseEntities();
        public Student_Mast getStudentByID()
        {
            Student_Mast student = db.Student_Mast.Where(i => i.StudID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            return student;
        }
    }
}
```

and **StudentController.cs**

```
public class UpdateController : Controller
{
    DemoDatabaseEntities db = new DemoDatabaseEntities();
    Student _bal = new Student();
    / GET: Update
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Student_Mast model = new Student_Mast();
        model = _bal.getStudentByID();
        model.First_Name = "Hardik";
        model.Last_Name = "Gondalia";
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
}
```

But db.savechanges() doesn't update the record.
Instead of this if I update record like below, it works
**StudentController.cs**

```
public class UpdateController : Controller
{
    DemoDatabaseEntities db = new DemoDatabaseEntities();
    Student _bal = new Student();
    / GET: Update
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Student_Mast model = new Student_Mast();
        model = db.Student_Mast.Where(i => i.StudID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        model.First_Name = "Hardik";
        model.Last_Name = "Gondalia";
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are retrieving the record from a different instance of your DbContext, it is unable to save it.
The solution would be to add a constructor to your Student class that takes a DbContext instance and saves it to the variable you have.

```
public class Student
{
    private DemoDatabaseEntities db = null;

    public Student(DemoDatabaseEntities dbContext){
    {
        this.db = dbContext;
    }

    public Student_Mast getStudentByID()
    {
        Student_Mast student = db.Student_Mast.Where(i => i.StudID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        return student;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the same database entity class `DemoDatabaseEntities` to the `Student` class. Do like this instead

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.DAL
{
    public class Student
    {
        DemoDatabaseEntities db;
        public Student(DemoDatabaseEntities _db)
        {
           this.db = _db
        }

        public Student_Mast getStudentByID()
        {
            Student_Mast student = db.Student_Mast
                             .Where(i => i.StudID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            return student;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in `StudentController` you will do this

```
public class UpdateController : Controller
{
    DemoDatabaseEntities db = new DemoDatabaseEntities();
    Student _bal = new Student(db);
    / GET: Update
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Student_Mast model = new Student_Mast();
        model = _bal.getStudentByID();
        model.First_Name = "Hardik";
        model.Last_Name = "Gondalia";
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is actually using of same database context object for both database operations, i.e to get students and to update back to db.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because `_bal.getStudentByID();` is getting `Student` entity from another EF context and this entity is detached from `db` context.

You can attach entity to your context or pass existing context as a dependency to `Student` class

In first case, updated version of **StudentController.cs** will contain following code:

```
public class UpdateController : Controller
{
    DemoDatabaseEntities db = new DemoDatabaseEntities();
    Student _bal = new Student();
    / GET: Update
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Student_Mast model = new Student_Mast();
        model = _bal.getStudentByID();
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified

        model.First_Name = "Hardik";
        model.Last_Name = "Gondalia";
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
}
```

What happening in second case is already answered above

Comment: Your code also works for me  db.Entry(model ).State = EntityState.Modified. What is best practice though?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers I am suggesting you to pass context as a dependency to all data fetching services, since it's hard to manage multiple contexts. I just show you why your code was not working exactly

Answer (score 1):

Your issue in your first example is because you're getting the `student` entity from a different data context instance. You have two options here, implement an `Update` method in your `Student` class to save changes in the same `DbContext` instance where the student entity comes from, which is a bad design, you shouldn't define these kind of methods in your entities (research about `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` patterns), or define the update in your controller as you try in your second example:

```
 var model = db.Student_Mast.FirstOrDefault(i => i.StudID == 1);
 model.First_Name = "Hardik";
 model.Last_Name = "Gondalia";
 db.SaveChanges();
```